# как сделать элемент родительским?

Tags: html, css, padding

```
  <body>
    <header class="main_header">
    <div class="square"></div>
    </header>
</body>



.main_header {
            width:1400px;
            height:230px;
            background:#fffdd0;
        }
        .square {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background:gray;
            padding:65px 1090px 65px 210px; 
        }
```

как указать положение .square относительно main_header, чтобы с помощью padding можно было поставить .square точно куда мне нужно? У меня получается какое-то неведомое изменение .square, где он каким-то образом сам меняется по высоте и ширине, когда я указываю padding.
Что мне делать если нужно[image] как на картинке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> padding:65px 1090px 65px 210px;
> ```

Это должно быть у заголовка.

Comment: немного не понял, что значит заголовок?

Comment: @Степан Слово "header" по-русски означает "заголовок".

Comment: спасибо, но я теперь вообще не понимаю как это работает

Comment: @Степан Это нормальное состояние современного разработчика :).